# Magento 2 : Error When searching in the grid of a custom module

Tags: admin, magento-2.1, grid

I have a problem in my custom module when search using title in the admin grid and also the next page of grid. Sorry for the image erasures.

Correct me if I'm wrong in my title of this question.

Thank you.

[image]

This will be the error message in the console when opened

[image]

Comment: Assume your ui component is working fine, remove cache and check with other browsers.

Comment: Hmmmm I'll try and let you know when it work. Thanks

Comment: did you check your PHP error logs? 500 response code most likely is caused by some PHP errors

Comment: what version of Magento you are using. Please can you give more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some debug tricks useful for your issue:

- Turn on developer mode in .htacess file if you are using apache by adding SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer
- Uncomment `#ini_set('display_errors', 1);` line in `app/bootstrap.php` file
- Visit `managefaqs/index/....` url in separate browser tab and find the error message